# Saving Dicitionary with NSDate() as a key to Parse.com fails

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to save a dictionary of type `[NSDate: Double]` to the `PFUser.currentUser's` record:

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()!
let date = NSDate()
user["savedDictionary"] = [date: 1.0] // error, see below. ["test": 1.0] works though

user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        print("Dictionary uploaded!")
    } else {
       print(error)
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
Caught "NSInvalidArgumentException" with reason "Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary":
```

This error also causes the `PFUser.currentUser`to log out.

Comment: The error message seems to include the reason for the problem: a key should be a String - not an NSDate.

Comment: So there is no way to save NSDate as a key for dictionaries on parse?

Comment: No, according to the JSON specification all keys must be strings and you neither can save `NSDate` objects as values. A workaround is to create the time interval relative to UNIX or Cocoa reference date and use its string representation. On destination convert the time interval back to a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the date key to a string:

```
let date = NSDate()
let df = NSDateFormatter()

// set a format. just an example
// 2012-01-04T08:21:04.674+02:00
df.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSSZZZZZ"


let str = df.stringFromDate(date)
assert(str != nil)

myDict[str] = value
```